# Strange effects of running bash/perl code for replacing a string in multiple files

Tags: bash, perl, replace

I have following three files with following content:

```
    1.txt             2.txt           3.txt
    ------------------------------------------
    1.txt             2.txt           3.txt
    text sample       text sample     text sample
    sample text       sample text     sample text
```

While writing code to replace the word 'sample' with the word 'changed' in all three files using a single bash command line with perl code I become aware that I am missing some important piece of understanding bash and/or perl in order to fix the problems I run into using following code:

```
$ perl -pe 's/sample/changed/' < 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt > 1a.txt 2a.txt 3a.txt
```

The result of executing the line above is:

```
    1a.txt            2a.txt          3a.txt
    ------------------------------------------
    2.txt               NOT             NOT
    text changed      CREATED         CREATED
    changed text
    3.txt
    text changed
    changed text
```

In order to fix the problem with:

```
Can't open 2a.txt: No such file or directory, <> line 6.
Can't open 3a.txt: No such file or directory, <> line 6.
```

I have changed the code to:

```
$ perl -pe 's/sample/changed/' < 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt > 1a.txt > 2a.txt > 3a.txt
```

which runs without any complaints, but gives as result:

```
    1a.txt            2a.txt          3a.txt
    ------------------------------------------
    EMPTY             EMPTY           2.txt
     FILE              FILE           text changed
                                      changed text
                                      3.txt
                                      text changed
                                      changed text
```

instead of what I have expected it to do:

```
    1a.txt            2a.txt          3a.txt
    ------------------------------------------
    1.txt             2.txt           3.txt
    text changed      text changed    text changed
    changed text      changed text    changed text
```

My question in this context is:

**What piece of information am I missing in my understanding** of how bash and perl work to come up with a right command to perform the substitution and especially what am I missing to understand how it comes that the result for the file `1.txt` is not written to the output files in both of the upper cases?

Comment: Shell Redirection happens/performed before anything else, so the `> file` creates it if not exists or truncates it, if it does.

Comment: See `LESS='+/^REDIRECTION' man bash` and `LESS='+/^EXPANSION' man bash`

Comment: `for file in {1..3}.txt; do perl -i ... "$file"; done`

Comment: @Jetchisel : OK this explains why perl complains about not existing files in the first command-line variant. Perl tries to get input from this files, but they are not there not created by the redirection, right? This explains also why the first two files of the triple redirection are empty and Perl writes then to the last one which is the newest `stdout` passed to Perl, right?

Comment: What is a system for naming new files?  Enumerate them somehow? (a1, a2...)  Or derive from input files? (in1A, in2A)

Comment: Thank you ALL for your responses where any of them helped step by step to resolve my confusion by providing the missing pieces for completing the puzzle. To mark this question as answered I have to accept one of the answers and can't accept all of them, so I have chosen one which in my eyes gave me the final breakthrough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
perl -pe's/sample/changed/' <1.txt 2.txt 3.txt >1a.txt 2a.txt 3a.txt
```

is the same as

```bash
perl -pe's/sample/changed/' 2.txt 3.txt 2a.txt 3a.txt <1.txt >1a.txt
```

Obviously wrong.

---

Since there's only one stdout.

```bash
perl -pe's/sample/changed/' <1.txt 2.txt 3.txt >1a.txt >2a.txt >3a.txt
```

is the same as

```bash
perl -pe's/sample/changed/' 2.txt 3.txt <1.txt >3a.txt
```

Obviously wrong.

---

You could use

```bash
for f in 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt; do
   perl -pe's/sample/changed/' "$f" >"$f.new"
done
```

If you really want `1a.txt`, you could use the following:

```bash
for f in {1..3}; do
    perl -pe's/sample/changed/' "$f.txt" > "${f}a.txt"
done
```

or

```bash
for f in 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt; do
   d="$( dirname "$f" )
   b="$( basename "$f" .txt)
   nf="$d/${b}a.txt"
   perl -pe's/sample/changed/' "$f" >"$nf"
done
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness here the further missing pieces of information which finally resolved my confusion: 1. **shell redirection is managed by the shell and not by the program being called.** 2. **redirection takes only one file** 3. **Shell Redirection happens (is performed) before anything else, so `>  file.ext` creates file.ext or truncates it, if it exists**

Answer (score 3):

The missing information: redirection only takes one file.

How to fix the code: Use the `-i` flag.

```
perl -i~ -pe 's/sample/changed/' -- 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

It will change the files "in place", leaving 1.txt~, 2.txt~, and 3.txt~ as backups.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I am and was aware of `-i` . That was what I have started with and it worked OK. Now I want to get the result of substitution written to another files. *redirection only takes one file* does not explain how it comes that `perl -pe 's/sample/changed/' < 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt > 1a.txt > 2a.txt > 3a.txt` does what it does. My expectation was that PERL somehow will take one file out of the redirection. The triple redirection works ... but I have no idea why the first two files are empty and why there is no result of substitution in txt.1 stored in the third file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the concept of file descriptors. The shell and most programs by default sends output to FD 1, stderr to FD 2, and reads input from FD 0. Redirection in simplified terms is all about assigning which file or device these file descriptors represent. If you specify multiple `>`'s, only the last one gets effectively represented by FD 1, at least by concept. Redirection is also is managed by the shell and not the program being called.

If you want `1.txt`, `2.txt`, and `3.txt` processed separately have the result saved on their "a" counterparts, you can use a loop.

```
for f in {1..3}; do
    perl -pe 's/sample/changed/' "$f.txt" > "${f}a.txt"
done
```

I think it can also be done inside Perl itself, but I don't know Perl.

Comment: Thank you for your response explaining to me how it comes that perl output is written only to one file, but does not resolve my confusion with not understanding how does it come that the result of substitution for `1.txt` is not written to the file receiving perl output?

Comment: @Claudio Apparently Perl works like this: If you specify no argument, it will try to read input from STDIN which is FD 0, which is also the one that handles the redirection of `1.txt`. So in that scenario Perl reads `1.txt`. But if you add a file argument to Perl, it reads that file instead. And the input is ignored. Redirection only respects the argument next to it for redirection.  The following arguments are passed to the program as program's arguments.  In `< 1.txt 2.txt` for example, `1.txt` is used for redirection and `2.txt` is used as an argument. Same happens to the output redirector.

Answer (score 1):

The main question, about redirections in this case, has been answered. However, dealing with redirections in the shell can get messy if there is more to do, and I'd like to remind that once a Perl program *is* involved anyway it is simple to also deal with files in it.

So read and process input files and write the corresponding output files all in Perl, one by one. A command-line program ("one-liner") seems to be desired

```
perl -MPath::Tiny -we'
    path("new_$_")->spew( path($_)->slurp =~ s/sample/changed/gr ) 
        for @ARGV;
' *.txt
```

This uses a library to conveniently read and write files, and I use  [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny).  There are other libraries for these tasks, or it can be done by hand (easy but more verbose).

Some details

- `@ARGV` contains command-line arguments, so here the names of files to process
- `Path::Tiny` library operates by creating an object, `path($filename)`, for an exisitng or a new (to be written) file, and applying methods to it
- `path($_)->slurp` reads file with the name `$_` (from `@ARGV`) into a string, to which a regex can be bound directly
- With the modifier `/r` the regex returns the processed string
- That returned string is written to a file with `path("new_$_")->spew(...)`

Answer (score 0):

##### The piece of information you are missing and which causes your confusion is lack of proper understanding of shell redirection.

Important to understand in this context is that:

- **redirection is an independent standalone command/instruction** and does not need any other content on the command line to become executed. The consequence of this is that already a **standalone `~ $ > fname.ext`** can
- - create a new fname.ext file if it does not yet exist
- - truncate an existing file (**!delete its entire content!**)
- **shell redirection is managed by the shell** and not by the program being called
- **it doesn't matter where in the single instruction the redirection occur**. So
- - `> txt.1 echo "sample text"` does the same as `echo "sample text" > txt.1`
- **redirection takes only one file** so `< 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt` makes only the content of `1.txt` file available on `stdin`
  (not the content of 2.txt and 3.txt too)
- **redirection happens (is performed) before anything else**
- using `> file.ext` anywhere in the text of the command line (including also a standalone occurrence) results in:
- - creation of the `file.ext` if it does not exist
- - truncation of `file.ext` if it exists ( making it empty / having no content )
- - assignment of `stdout` to the file

---

Now with all of the above in mind let's explain how it comes what you describe in your question:

The reason why when executing

```
$ perl -pe 's/sample/changed/' < 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt > 1a.txt 2a.txt 3a.txt
```

files 2a.txt and 3a.txt are not created is that redirection takes only one file, the `1a.txt` so 2a.txt and 3a.txt were passed as parameter to perl and perl complained then that they don't exist.

The reason why when executing

```
$ perl -pe 's/sample/changed/' < 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt > 1a.txt > 2a.txt > 3a.txt
```

the file `1.txt` was skipped from consideration by pearl is the redirection `< 1.txt` which takes `1.txt` file out of the command-line parameter list passed to pearl. Assigning stdin to 1.txt has no effect here because pearl won't use stdin as it found 2.txt and 3.txt as files to use as input and ignores therefore stdin.

The reason why 1a.txt and 2a.txt are empty is creation/truncation of these files by the redirections `> 1a.txt` and `> 2a.txt`.

The 3.txt file contains the perl script output because the command line was evaluated by bash from the left to the right with the consequence that the last assignment to stdout was assigning to it the 3a.txt file and all the perl output to stdout went then to 3a.txt .